# missing ) after argument list in html form code

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to use the following code, to display $formcode, which is the html code for a form, in a popup windows. I understand that it is not an ideal method, but I want to understand why it is not working.

```
<?php
$blah = "Well"; $test = "Done";
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="fetchlayers.js"></script>';
$formcode = "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data \"><label for=\"file\">Filename:</label><input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" id=\"file\"/> <br /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"setTimeout(function() { alert('$blah'); },1250);\" /></form>";


echo "<h1>hello</h1>
<div id='form'>
<a href='#' onclick=\"createpopup('" . htmlentities($formcode) . "'); return false;\">
click here</a>
</div>";
```

In Firebug, I get missing ) after argument list which seems somewhat arbitrary, as the right number of parentheses is there.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code this produces, which is what the browser sees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's this or not, because I can't test it, but check the alert('$blah')

it should be with \' I think

```
alert(\'$blah\')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by not working, but if you mean the window is not popping up then the problem is in your **fetchlayer.js** file.  But other wise let us know what exactly what you mean by not working.

Answer (score 0):

The content of $formcode needs to have the single quotes double-escaped:

```
alert(\\'$blah\\');
```

so that the string contains "\'".