# Why would I be getting a "missing ) after argument list" error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebug

I am working on an AJAX system to submit a form, but I can't even get my JavaScript to load, the Firebug report is below.

```
missing ) after argument list
    else if( httpRequest.responseText == 'already logged in' )\n
```

I poked around the internet and SO, but all I found was errors in quoting.  ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865928/missing-after-argument-list), [Another Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832615/missing-after-argument-list-in-html-form-code)).  I don't have anything misquoted, so I really don't see what is going on.  More of my code is below.
(Some unrelated function calls to remove loading messages are removed.)

```
if(httpRequest.responseText != "failure")  // Works fine!
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "[Success message]";
    setTimeout("2000", function(){ window.location.assign("[link to page]");
}
else if(httpRequest.responseText == 'already logged in')  // Similar to above, but fails
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "[error message]";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "[error message]";
}
```

Might anyone know why this error is called?
(For more members, it might be useful to outline what things cause this error, which would allow this page to work with other code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you split your code up a bit more you see the problem:

```
setTimeout("2000", function()
{
    window.location.assign("[link to page]");
```

So you are missing a } and a );

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    window.location.assign("[link to page]");
},2000);
```

Edit: The order of the arguments is wrong as well like Caspar pointed out.

Comment: OK, thank you, wondered what went wrong, and didn't look at the surrounding code.  I got distracted by the line mentioned in Firebug.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes you need a bit of distance to your code to find an error. Especially when you've been working on it longer. :)

Answer (score 7):

the line

```
setTimeout("2000", function(){ window.location.assign("[link to page]");
```

misses a `})`  causing the next line to fail (**the whole syntax is wrong** anyway:)

it should be

```
 setTimeout (function(){ window.location.assign("[link to page]") } , 2000 );
```

`setTimeout` takes a **function** as the **first parameter** and an **integer as the second one**.

[more here](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)

Answer (score 3):

```
   setTimeout("2000", function(){ window.location.assign("[link to page]");
```

should be

```
   setTimeout("2000", function(){ window.location.assign("[link to page]");});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `});` here

```
setTimeout("2000", function(){ window.location.assign("[link to page]");
```

should be

```
setTimeout("2000", function(){ window.location.assign("[link to page]"); });
```